# Checking if the input is checked always returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

i am trying like this:

```
if($('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0 == false){
```

but this will allways return true, doesn't matter if is checked or not

note: there is only one checkbox in the DOM.

Comment: Seems to work for me (Chrome 19). http://jsfiddle.net/WzvWr/

Comment: The logic in that `if` statement is breaking my head :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
if(!$("input:checkbox").is(":checked")){
  //not checked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(!$('input:checkbox').prop('checked')){ //do stuff
```

Note: jquery version > 1.6 required for `prop()`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length ==0){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($("input:checkbox").is(":checked")){
      alert('checkbox is checked')
    }
    else
    {
      alert('checkbox is not checked')
    }
```

if you have multiple check boxes in your form than iterate each like this

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
      var value = $(this).attr('value');
      alert(value);// it returns on or off, depends on checked or unchecked               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        unchecked: function (obj) {
            return ((obj.type == 'checkbox' || obj.type == 'radio') && !$(obj).is(':checked'));
        }
    });


    if(($('input:unchecked').length > 0)=== false)
```